# Adding a variable into all log messages

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I'm using `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26` to write logs from a Java application. My `log4j.properties` looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console

# add a ConsoleAppender to the logger stdout to write to the console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# use a simple message format
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern={\
  "time":"%d{ISO8601}",\
  "level":"%p",\
  "class":"%c{1.}",\
  "message":"%m",\
  "thread":"%t",\
  "fileName":"PLACEHOLDER_FILE_NAME"\
  }%n
```

I need to replace `PLACEHOLDER_FILE_NAME` with the name of a file that is fed into the application as a CLA at startup. rather How can this be done? I've looked into `java.util.logging.Formatter` but I'm not convinced that's the best way as it seems to override `log4j.properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read system property eg. `${file.name}` in log4j config:
Then, you just need to set this property before log4j reads this config eg. at startup specyfying it as -Dfile.name=filenamePath

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console

# add a ConsoleAppender to the logger stdout to write to the console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# use a simple message format
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern={\
  "time":"%d{ISO8601}",\
  "level":"%p",\
  "class":"%c{1.}",\
  "message":"%m",\
  "thread":"%t",\
  "fileName":"${file.name}"\
  }%n
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems much better than implementing a custom handler.